# get_header action not working

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am trying to change the header template using the `get_header` action but it wont change anyway I try to do it.

Here is what I tried by adding this in functions.php:

```
function prefix_new_header() {
    return 'newtmpl';
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'prefix_new_header' );
```

I have in the theme folder a file called **header-newtmpl.php**

I’ve tried different priorities (1, 10, 99), but it doesn’t work.

Is there something I am missing? Thanks for any help!

You can try this in twentysixteen, if you want to test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364356/is-it-possible-to-set-a-different-header-per-page-using-get-header-action-in-w

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional logic. E.G.

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

The file names for the home and 404 headers should be header-home.php and header-404.php respectively.

So in your page-template just add

```
        get_header( 'newtmpl' );
```

dunno why you should use a function for that.